# Powershell scripts failing in SQL Agent jobs

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I have sql agent jobs which call certain Stored Procedures based on some condition. The logic was implemented in powershell. Recently all the powershell jobs in sql agent started failing with error message:

The step did not generate any output. Process exit code -2146232576. Anyone have insight on this issue?

Edit:
Around the time the jobs started failing following entries are registered in Windows evenlog setup:

Initiating changes to turn off update MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2 of package PowerShell-V2-ServerCore. Client id: DISM Package Manager Provider.

Selectable update MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2 of package PowerShell-V2-ServerCore was successfully turned off.

I'm not familair with Operating system level changes.Could anyone interpret what's going on?

Comment: Is Powershell available on the system? The log entry looks like it was disabled.

Comment: @vonPryz  Yes from Server I opened Powershell ISE and executed the commands from the job and it succeeded. Issues is only while running from Sql Agent Job

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the SQL Agent is using the PS v2 Engine to execute your scripts and your server admins have disabled PS v2 using DISM. Yes your scripts will work fine in ISE because they almost always are backwards compatible with newer versions of PS 3,4,5,6 etc. The SQL Agent job is running a command before your scripts telling Powershell to use the v2 engine, which the feature is no longer installed.